# how to make virtual keyboard (jquery) work with angular 2 in an electron app

Tags: angular, electron, virtual-keyboard

In my Angular2 project(Angular Cli), i need  virtual keyboard, trying to use Virtual keyboard 
[git url](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard) 
i did

1. npm install jquery
2. added script in angularcli.json file

> "scripts": [
>           "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
>         ],

i have called keyboard function on function call as below:
 `$("#keyboard").click(function(){
        $(this).keyboard();
      });
    });`

But im getting following error:[This is my screenshot of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPlHB.png)

Comment: Use this instead: https://github.com/antonio-spinelli/ng-virtual-keyboard

Comment: Hey, Do you have any example where this virtual keyboard is used with angular 2?

Comment: Sorry, I don't... I don't know angular 2, so I'm not much help here

Comment: Okay no problem :) I have it figured out!

Comment: Please add an answer here so that others with the same problem may benefit.

Comment: Hello Ankita how you figured out ?

Answer (score 1):

1. My main problem was Jquery not being recognized by the electron.I was getting "Jquery not defined"error. I fixed it by adding the following to my index.html file:

   ```
   <script>if (typeof module === 'object') {window.module = module; module = undefined;}</script>
   <script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>    
   <script src="scripts/vendor.js"></script>    
   <script>if (window.module) module = window.module;</script>
   ```
2. This fixed my Jquery error. Then I could use the keyboard from https://github.com/antonio-spinelli/ng-virtual-keyboard by following the steps given in this github link.

Comment: Steps are given in the GitHub link for AngularJs, how did you integrate the same in Angular2+? @ankita